# Calculate a new matrix with multiple possible outcomes from pre-existing variables

Tags: r, matrix, calculated-columns

I need to overlay two large matrices (or columns from a merger of the two) to generate a final matrix for analysis. I have a series of points where counts were made 3 times per year for a number of year (generating e.g. counts 2000_1, 2000_2, etc.), but sometimes a point wasn’t done for one reason or another. If the point was done, there may have been detections or there may not. So there are essentially three possible results for each cell in the final matrix to be calculated from the other two values. If no sampling occurred at the point on an occasion, I need the value “.”; if sampling occurred but no detections occurred, I need a “0”, and if sampling occurred and 1-n individuals were detected, I need a “1”.

In the sample data below, I’ve combined the two matrices to simplify but note that the actual datasets would be about 750 records over 64 columns. In column 1, the point ID is provided. The next 5 columns (pt.x) provide whether a count was conducted in a given year_rotation, and the last 5 how many if any detections. An NA is no data, and should only occur when sampling didn’t occur, but could happen if there was sampling but no zero was entered.

Sample

```
Point <- c(“A194”,” A234”,”A83”,” K37”,” TS47”)
p0.1 <- c(1,1,1,1,0)
p0.2 <- c(1,1,1,1,0)
p0.3 <- c(1,1,1,1,0)
p1.1 <- c(1,0,1,0,0)
p1.2 <- c(1,0,1,1,0)
d0.1 <- c(1,0,0,3,NA)
d0.2 <- c(0,0,2,2,NA)
d0.3 <- c(0,0,0,1,NA)
d1.1 <- c(0,NA,0,NA,NA)
d1.2 <- c(0,NA,0,0,NA)
```

And here's what I'd like to end up with:

```
Point f0.1 f0.2 f0.3 f1.1 f1.2
A194    1    0    0    0    0
A234    0    0    0    .    .
A83    0    1    1    0    0
K37    1    1    1    .    1
TS47    .    .    .    .    .
```

Can anyone suggest a clean, general way to do this so that it is transferrable to the larger dataset or, ultimately to other similar datasets? I can either start with this scenario, with points and detections (p and d columns above) in the same dataframe, or with two frames, one for each condition. 
Thanks for your help, and sorry if there are format issue with my post. Relatively new to formatting such.

Comment: does your point matrix contain NA values for the points that were not done, or are they just missing entirely?  Slightly different question, can you assume the dimensions of the point and detection matrices are the same?

Comment: The point matrix should only have 1/0 values and should include every point*rep. Zeros indicate not done. The detections matrix will contain NAs when there was no count, and potentially when a count was done, but someone didn't enter any response data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you derive your result:

- Why do you need the `p*` vectors?
- Why is `f1.2` 0 . 0 1 .? How do you get the last 1?

Here is my attempt (based on what I've understood from your question):

```
Point <- c("A194","A234","A83","K37","TS47")
d0.1 <- c(1,0,0,3,NA)
d0.2 <- c(0,0,2,2,NA)
d0.3 <- c(0,0,0,1,NA)
d1.1 <- c(0,NA,0,NA,NA)
d1.2 <- c(0,NA,0,0,NA)

#create this matrix from whatever you start with
d <- ls(pattern="d\\d+\\.\\d+")
m <- do.call(cbind, mget(d))
rownames(m) <- Point

res <- (m>0)+0
colnames(res) <- gsub("d", "f", d)
```

I think you want to print `NA` values as `.`? I don't understand why you'd want that, but this achieves it:

```
#create a class with a print method that prints NA as .
class(res) <- c("myclass", class(res))
print.myclass <- function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- "."
  print.data.frame(as.data.frame(x))
}

res
#      f0.1 f0.2 f0.3 f1.1 f1.2
# A194    1    0    0    0    0
# A234    0    0    0    .    .
# A83     0    1    0    0    0
# K37     1    1    1    .    0
# TS47    .    .    .    .    .
```

Comment: An NA (in the d vectors) could mean, a count was conducted, but no information was entered (meaning no information was entered about non-detections) or (most likely) simply that no count occurred on that occasion.To create the more conservative dataset, I want to use the date information for each point independent of the count of detections to tell me if a count was done, and then, given that a count occurred, what was observed.

Comment: The f1.2 issue was a mistake on my part. I wanted to provide a broader range of examples. It should be (0 . 0 0 .) .  And lastly, I need the “.” for non-counts because the package I’m analyzing the data in allow the user to censor those data points where no count occurred.

Comment: I don't understand. If a count was conducted, but no information recorded, what is the result supposed to be? Please clarify in your question (without all that prose, maybe use some if/then syntax). Also, in R missing values are encoded as `NA`. If you need actually `.` as a value (in contrast to just printing it), it's not possible to mix that with numeric values (in a matrix or data.frame column). If this is used to create an input file for third party software, you could specify `na="."` in `write.table`.

Comment: If p=1 AND d>0, f=1
If p=1 AND d=(0,NA), f=0
If p=0 AND d=(0,NA), f=NA
And although it shouldn’t happen, if p=0 AND d>0, f=99 just for QAQC value.

Thanks for the “NA” info. I haven’t used this data type in R until now, and some of the older 3rd party software (and associated literature) uses the “.” notation.